# handle more than one button with one event handler

Tags: vb.net

so this is my sub

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button1.Click


    Dim but As Integer
    If sender.text = "" Then


        but = Mid(sender.name.ToString, 7, Len(sender.name.ToString) - 6)

        i = Int(but / 9)
        j = but Mod 9 - 1
        If j < 0 Then
            i = i - 1
            j = 8
        End If
        If m(i, j) = 0 Then
            sender.visible = False
        Else
            If m(i, j) = -1 Then
                MsgBox("you lose")
            Else
                sender.text = m(i, j)
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

this sub needs to be done on 81 different buttons
but its not logical to write handles button1.click,button2.click....
is there is a simple and smarter solution ?

Comment: use "addhandler", just loop through your controls and check if they're a button, then add handler.

Comment: FYI, I posted an answer at the question this was marked as a dupe of that might be helpful to you.